# Xcode doesn't jump to build failure

Tags: swift, xcode

I run build in Xcode, and something is wrong in another file, it just says build failed - but doesn't take me away from the file I'm in.  If I click on the errors/warnings, I can see a list, and if I click on an error it then takes me to that error, but when I hit the keystroke to build, and the build fails - I expect to be immediately taken to one of the errors, without having to explicitly browse there - like every other IDE since the beginning of time. Is there any way to configure Xcode to do that?

Comment: I see that as a positive.  if I'm working on something I don't want my IDE to lose the focus in my current file just to jump to what might be a known error I have no interest in fixing at that point.   And on a practical note, how should XCode prioritise the errors so it knows where to go to?

Comment: I don't know why you would want this, but you can navigate between issues quickly with `Command` + `'`

Comment: Choose the menu command `Xcode > Behaviors > Edit Behaviors...`. Select `Build: Fails`.  Click the box next to `Navigate to` and select `first new issue`. More details in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/CustomizingYourWorkflow.html).

Comment: Omg Kurt thank-you! -  you've dramatically improved my Xcode experience.   Want to post again as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Choose the menu command `Xcode > Behaviors > Edit Behaviors…`
2. Select `Build: Fails`.
3. Click the box next to `Navigate to` and select `first new issue`.

More details in [the Xcode documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/CustomizingYourWorkflow.html).